# Haskell - Convert De Bruijn terms to Lambda terms (and vice-versa)

Tags: haskell, lambda

I have an assignment to write a Haskell program capable of converting De Bruijn terms to Lambda terms, and to convert Lambda terms into De Bruijn terms, and also to check if the terms are 'closed'.

I am not looking for someone to do this assignment for me, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I am largely clueless about how to even get started with this.

So, my biggest questions are: what's the difference between a De Bruijn term and a Lambda term?
I understand what it means for a variable to be 'closed', but how could I check for that in Haskell?

Any other assistance that you can think of would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full assignment:

> The (usual) lambda terms are defined as the data type:
>
> ```
> data Term = Var Int | Lam Int Term | App Term Term deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
> ```
>
> where variables are represented as integers. A term is called closed
>   if for every `i` in `Var i` there's a term of the from `Lam i <subterm>` on
>   the path from it to the root, providing it a binding.
>
> De Bruijn terms are defined as the data type:
>
> ```
> data BTerm =BVar Int | BLam BTerm | BApp BTerm BTerm deriving (Eq,  Show, Read)
> ```
>
> Write a Haskell function `db2lam` that transforms a de Bruijn term into
>   a lambda term. Write a Haskell function `lam2db` that transforms a
>   lambda term into a Bruijn term.
>
> Write a function `isClosed` that tests if a lambda term is closed. Write
>   a function `isClosed` that tests if a de Bruijn term is closed.
>
> Chose one of the following two subjects:
>
> a) Implement normal order beta reduction for de Bruijn terms
>   b) Implement normal order beta reduction for (the usual) lambda terms

Thanks a lot for any assistance(Large or small)! I'm in the early stages of learning Haskell, so sorry for being so unsure! This assignment is way over my head at this time.

Comment: You need to ask your professor/teacher about the "if a de Bruijn term is closed" part, because as far as I can tell you don't have the structure to reliably do `lam2b` if that lambda is not closed. What you need to unclose them is to either add another constructor `BFree Int | BVar Int | ...` or, as one paper does, to add a type parameter `data BTerm v = BVar v | BLam (BTerm (Maybe v)) | BApp BTerm BTerm` . The `Maybe` then uses `Just x` to indicate freedom or `Nothing` to indicate boundness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially your assignment is asking you to explore the difference between "named" and "nameless" lambda calculi implementations. Typically when we, as humans, write lambda terms we write them using named variables like

```
(\g -> (\f -> f (\x -> g x))) (\m -> m)
```

which works under the assumption that whenever a name is "bound" by a lambda then we can go and uniquely track down all of the places where that name is being used in the body of the lambda. In particular, concepts like "shadowing" become important.

As a small side tangent, it's always important to note that when we're writing down named lambda terms that they are non-unique. If we're really pedantic then we'd note that `(\x -> x)` and `(\y -> y)` are different terms. We understand that they ultimately represent the same "process", though and so introduce the notion of *alpha-equivalence* to handle the fact that two similar named lambda terms might actually be functionally identical. This is the statement that named lambda terms are "unique up to renaming" where "renaming" works the way you think it ought to.

A more important facet of named lambda terms is "capture via substitution", a flaw in naive implementations. In particular, while alpha-equivalence suggests that two terms are equal up to renaming, this can be violated by certain pathological, *clashing* renamings such as

```
(\x -> (\q -> q x))  ====>  (\x -> (\x -> x x))
```

While renaming `q -> x` might feel permissible, because I changed how the `q`-lambda term "captures" variables it caused the meaning of my program to change. This is obviously pathological here, but it's also fairly easy to accidentally enact when implementing substitution.

Capture-avoiding substitution is generally an important thing to enact. As fragments of your LC ADT move around and are interpreted in their new, substituted contexts their meaning changes and that change must be accounted for. That said, capture-avoiding substitutions using named terms can be expensive because one must be know the context of the entire term to recognize which names are at risk of capture.

So for these two reasons, the need for alpha-equivalence and the risk of capturing, named terms, despite their human-language familiarity, are not always the best choice.

So now we turn to nameless terms. The de Bruijn terms your assignment asks you to implement are a nameless variety. In particular, if you look at the ADT it's clear that the `BLam`s no longer specify which variable is bound by them---we're instead forced to determine the meaning of variables from the structure of the ADT alone.

In particular, the rule is that variables are pointers to the lambda which bound them. A `BVar n` binds to the lambda which is `n` `BLam`s above it. So if we were to make a translator from named to nameless terms they'd look like

```
(\x -> x)            ===>  (\ 0)
(\x -> (\q -> q x))  ===>  (\ (\ 0 1))

(\g -> (\f -> f (\x -> g x))) (\m -> m)
===>
(\ (\ 0 (\ 2 0))) (\ 0)
```

Nameless terms are kind of difficult to read as humans, but they have two nice qualities:

1. There is no such thing as alpha-equivalence any longer; two nameless terms represent the same computation exactly when they are structurally equal
2. As variables are very systematically "named" due exactly to the structure of the term implementing capture avoidance is somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 3):

A variable with a [De Bruijn index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) refers to the lambda that many steps away from it. The simplest example is `BLam (BVar 0)`, which is the identity function. (I like to start counting at `0` *skipped* lambdas, other authors start counting at the `1`st lambda.) The variable `BVar 0` is bound by the lambda with no lambdas in-between.

A variable in the usual lambda terms refers to the closest lambda with the same name. The simplest example is the identity function `Lam 1 (Var 1)`, which can be written using any variable name we want; `Lam 2 (Var 2)`, `Lam 3 (Var 3)`, ... are all the same identity function. The lambdas in the usual lambda terms need to know the name of the variable they are binding. The lambdas in the De Bruijn indexed terms didn't need a variable name, they always start binding the variable `BVar 0`.

Comment: Let me guess: starting with 0 is cleaner when you use types to guarantee the De Bruijn indices are all in bounds?

Comment: @dfeuer No, I like `0` because lists are indexed starting at `0`. If you are binding variables (alpha-reducing) and have a list `bindings` of what to bind them to where the most recently bound variable is at the head of the list and you are looking at `Var v` then the one you are looking for is `bindings !! v`.

Comment: @dfeuer You can see a simple example of keeping a list of bindings in *(spoilers ahead)* [implementing `db2lam` for this homework problem](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/087c3e50ecc53e0f04e9). In this case the bindings are just to the new variable names for the usual lambda terms. If type checking I'd probably start with 1, leaving 0 for those terms whose maximum index didn't escape; it's a clever idea and I'm not sure entirely how I'd go about it.

Answer (score 0):

(generic answer to all homework-type questions)

"This assignment is way over my head at this time."

Are you sure? Your teacher sets these assignments for a reason: they have a connection to the lecture. There's a 99.99 percent chance that you can do them with the knowledge you have.

Check your lecture notes, check the references that were given in the lecture (that means, go to the library). I am pretty sure that the answer to "what's the difference between a De Bruijn term and a Lambda term?" is in there somewhere.

If you don't find it after a reasonable effort, then check with your fellow students, then with your teaching assistant, then with your teacher.

Sadly, SO tolerates (even attracts) homework type questions (and rewards answering them) for reasons that are obvious (it increases their click count). This is helping SO (in the short term), but not the students (in the long run).